# How to get only the URL of one image from google search (API)

Tags: google-search-api

Is there a direct way of getting that url with custom search options?

Now i harvest the image url from the mobile page result (for example for an orange):

http://www.google.com/m/search?q=orange&site=images

Let's say i only want the url of the first image result for the word "orange" with a small image size.